# Show hidden element on <img> tag

Tags: html, css

I have an image in my HTML code:

```
<img src="main.jpg" />
```

I want to show a smaller linkable image over main.jpg when I hold mouse over main.jpg.
(This image is link)
I prefer to use smaller image by CSS.

I tried this:

```
<div class="img"><img src="main.jpg" /></div>
<div class="resize"><a href="resizepic.jpg">resize imgae</a></div>

.resize{
    background:url(resize.jpg) left top no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    desiplay:none;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

I want do this just with pure CSS (no JS)...Do you know a trick or an alternative way to  do it?

[image: The smaller image is on top left corner]

Comment: Put the `.resize` div inside the `.img` div which should have position relative.

Comment: you have a spelling mistake in your css "desiplay:none;" should be "display:none;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will solve your problem

```
<div class="img"> 
    <img src="main.jpg" /> 
    <div class="resize"><a href="resizepic.jpg">resize imgae</a></div>
</div>
```

Also correct your css class

change `desiplay:none;`  to `display:none;`

Comment: And resize imgae should be image I guess?